# Question about artificial gravity rotating ring-like space station

Tags: gravity, angular-velocity, centrifugal-force, space

What should be the  minimal radius of the so called ring-like space station to minimize the effects of rising masses moving from us and different gravities depending which way we run inside that space station?

Comment: These aren't duplicates, but here are some questions related to centrifugal gravity https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440275/123208 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/440278/123208 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441606/123208 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257848/123208

Comment: Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112354/123208

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"effects of rising masses moving from us"* ? In such a space station, "up" means towards the axis of rotation, so if the radius is small, it will be noticeable that the up vectors at 2 nearby points aren't parallel. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You seem to be confusing  mass with force

Comment: the latter effect is called the Eötvös Effect.

Answer (score 0):

The effects you describe will decrease as the radius increases, but will never go away.  You will have to decide what constitutes an acceptable level of inconvenience.